# Convert Text Value to Time Value in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to convert text to time. Basically I copy and pasted the total time of employees but it pastes as text value and then in order to add the time I have to convert it to time and I have to press F2 in each cell (LOTS OF CELLS FOR A LOT OF EMPLOYEES) and this really adds up time to get payroll in. Do you know of any function I can do to just convert from text value to time value faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have pasted data from an external source (e.g. web pages are horrific for this) into a worksheet and numbers, dates and/or times come in as textual representations rather than true numbers, dates and/or times usually the quickest method is to select the column and choose Data ► Text to Columns ► Fixed Width ► Finish. This forces Excel to reevaluate the text values and should revert the pseudo-numbers into their true numerical values.

If this occurs with formulas pasted into cells that are formatted as text or custom, first set the column to a *General* format then use Ctrl+H to Find what: = and Replace with: = and again Excel will reevaluate each cell's contents, replacing the text that looks like a formula with an operational formula.

One particular circumstance that might be worthy to note in a general sense is the use of the non-breaking space character (ASCII 160 or 0×A0) common in web pages so that table cells of datetimes will not wrap to a second line. If you have what appears to be a space that you simply cannot get rid of, use Ctrl+H to replace the non-breaking spaces with conventional spaces (or nothing). A non-breaking space can be generated on a keyboard by holding down one of the `Alt` keys while tapping 0·1·6·0 on the numpad (with Num Lock ON) then releasing the `Alt` key.

Comment: Awesome!!! I love it! Made my life soooo much easier!

Answer (score 7):

If you have a text value like `8:00` in, for example, cell `J42`, then put

```
=TIMEVALUE(J42)
```

into cell `K42` and you will get an Excel date/time value of eight hours. 
It will display as `0.33333333` by default (because 8 hours is ⅓ of a day),
but you can format it to display as a time value. 
And, depending on your needs,
you may want to copy column `K` and paste values over column `J`,
so you get rid of the text values and keep only the date/time values.

`TIMEVALUE()` does not handle negative values. 
If there's a possibility that your data will include negative times,
like `-8:00` (perhaps because you have time sheet corrections
or other adjustments to previously entered data),
you need a formula that handles the **`-`** explicitly:

```
=IF(LEFT(J42,1)="-", -TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(J42,LEN(J42)-1)), TIMEVALUE(J42))
```

Comment: What about negative time like `-0:30` formated with `[h]:00`

Comment: @Pierre: That’s an interesting question/observation.  (1) The question is about employee time sheets and payroll, so it seems unlikely that Jessica will have any negative values (unless as corrections for previously entered data).  But I won’t use that as a shield; I agree that it would be nice to have an answer that handles any reasonable input.  (2) For the record, none of the other answers support negative values either.  (3) In fact, if you type `-0:30` into a cell, it doesn’t work (although, somewhat surprisingly, `-"0:30"` does).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Furthermore, your question seems to be based on a false premise: In Excel 2013, even if I enter `-"0:30"` or `=-1/48` into a cell, I cannot get it to display as `-0:30` — custom format `[h]:00` doesn’t work for me.  (5) If you’re asking this question seriously, then the answer is a formula that handles the **`-`** explicitly: `=IF(LEFT(J42,1)="-", -TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(J42,LEN(J42)-1)), TIMEVALUE(J42))`.  I haven’t tested that exhaustively; go ahead and notify me if you find a case where it fails.

Answer (score 2):

For a time like `11:42:47.294` you can use this formula:

```
=TIME(MID(B13,SEARCH(":",B13,1)-2,2),MID(B13,SEARCH(":",B13,6)-2,2),MID(B13,SEARCH(":",B13,6)+1,6))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine the Substitue and TimeValue functions to strip out the extra spaces and/or other characters and leaves you with a properly formatted time.

EX

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," PST",""))
```

will get rid of a trailing space and 'PST' so that the TimeValue function can work on cell A1 that contains "11:58 AM PST"

Comment: This might not really be relevant for this question (i.e., for Jessica, who asked this question).  The question is about employee time sheets and payroll.  In my limited experience, time sheets contain time *durations* and not time *instants*.  For example, if a person worked from 9:00 AM to 5:00 PM (in some time zone), the time sheet would show only “8:00” (eight hours *duration* between 9 and 5, which equals the *difference* 17:00−9:00).  But I suppose that this extra step might be of some help to somebody else who finds this question as a result of a search.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all that, try highlighting the whole column. Then click on Text to Columns. Sounds odd, i know. Then just click Finish. It magically converts time or dates as a normal time or date...versus text.

Comment: I suggest that you read the accepted answer before you answer the question. It is the same as what you have mentioned. I see no value addition because of your answer

Answer (score 0):

If there is no formula (time value is not preceded by an equal sign) you can also utilize the first find/replace solution, but find: AM and replace: AM, then find: PM and replace: PM.

This will force excel to reevaluate the text values to time values.